# Default route not working when changed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, api

I created an API using Visual Studio and removed all the content I didn't want to use. Everything's fine til now. Now I'm trying to change the default route for my API but it's just not working. I want to call localhost and I want my API to redirect to QueryController.

My RouteConfig.cs is like this:

```
routes.MapRoute (
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Query", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

My QueryController.cs is like this:

```
public class QueryController: ApiController
{
    public ResultRecord Get ([FromUri] RequestRecord request)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas ();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure (WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters (GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes (RouteTable.Routes);     
}
```

When I call localhost:port/api/Query it works fine. But if I run only localhost:port it never reaches QueryController. Any ideas why? I've read some other threads but I just can't change this.

Comment: Do you have in Global.asax this line of code? `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`

Comment: In your url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}" you are missing `api`, it's not the problem?

Comment: @MacakM I noticed that. Actually after changing my WebApiConfig.cs it worked fine =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the route being used for your MVC controllers, not for your Web API controllers:

```
routes.MapRoute (
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Query", action = "Get", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Note how this route does not include `api/`.

You need to change your WebApi route, something like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Query", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This will allow you to target `localhost:port/api` and get to `QueryController.Get`.